# PHP ObjectId Deserialization

Tags: php, mongodb, symfony-2.1, jms-serializer

I'm trying to expose a REST API for the resource.

Environment: PHP/Symfony2/JMSSerializerBundle, MongoDB.

The MongoDB entity has some fields defined as ReferenceOne (simple=true), that means the DB fields holds ObjectId of the reference and PHP type gets it converted to the object.

In de/serialization I'd like to send/receive such fields as strings:

```
{  
   ...
   "user": "523178efac8c95ae77c285dc",
   ...
}
```

Object class:

```
class MyObject {

    /**
    * @MongoDB\ReferenceOne(targetDocument="MySpace\User", simple=true)
    * @Expose
    * @Type("string")  ???
    */
    private $user;
    ....
```

Is it possible to implement and if yes, so how?

Thanks!

P.S. In Java it available with @JsonDeserialize(using=...)